# Incorrect number of inversions in array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, mergesort, inversion

Could you please help me to find a mistake in my code on C# for counting inversions in array? The count is incorrect. For instance, in array {3, 8, 6, 1} it should be 4, but it's 3. However, it works fine for array {4, 3, 2, 1} and shows 6.
Every string from a text file (1111.txt )that program reads, contains 1 array element.
Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace C
{
class Program
{
public static long k1 = 0;
static long Marge_sort(int[] A, int p, int r)
{
int q = p;
if (r <= p) return 0;
q = (p + r) / 2;
C.Program.k1 = Marge_sort(A, p, q);
C.Program.k1 += Marge_sort(A, q + 1, r);
C.Program.k1 += Marge(A, p, q, r);
return C.Program.k1; 
}
static long Marge(int[] A, int p, int q, int r)
{
long k1 = 0;

int n1 = q - p+1 ;
int[] L = new int[n1+1];
int n2 = r - q;
int i;
int[] R = new int[n2+1];
for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
{
L[i] = 0;
L[i] = A[p + i ];
}
L[n1] = int.MaxValue;
for (i = 0; i < n2; i++)
{
R[i] = 0;
R[i] = A[q + i+1];
}
R[n2] = int.MaxValue;
int j = 0; i = 0;
for(int k=p;k<=r;k++)
{
if (L[i] <= R[j])
{
A[k] = L[i];
i++;
}
else
{
A[k] = R[j];
j++;
k1 = q - i+1 ;
}

}
return k1;

}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
long k1 = 0;
int leght = 0, el = 0;
int[] Ch = new int[leght];
StreamReader s = File.OpenText(@"D:\1111.txt");//IntegerArray
string read = null;
while ((read = s.ReadLine()) != null)
{
//Console.WriteLine(read);
leght++;
Array.Resize(ref Ch, leght);
Ch[el] = Convert.ToInt32(read);
el++;
}
s.Close();
k1=Marge_sort(Ch, 0, leght-1 );

Console.WriteLine("\n"+k1.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();

}

}
}
```

Comment: Could you improve the formatting?

Comment: For instance, in array {3, 6, 8, 1} it should be 4, but it's 3. I think it should be 3 only. (3,1), (6,1), (8,1)

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant {3, 8, 6, 1}

Comment: For {1, 2, 3, 4} it shows 2 inversions, when it should be 0

Comment: It returns 4 for array {3, 8, 6, 1}. Please try and check for mistakes and typos like this before posting your question. After someone has spent time trying to check something which turned out to be wrong, they are probably going to be reluctant to spend any more time helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line close to the end of `Marge`

```
k1 = q - i+1 ;
```

should be

```
k1 += n1 - i;
```

Firstly you are keeping a running total of how many elements of `L` an element of `R` has to be moved in front of. Therefore the operator should be `+=` not `=`.

Secondly `q` measures a position in the original array `A`. You are counting a number of elements in the small array `L`, and so you should be subtracting the index from `n1`, the size of that array (not including the guard value). If `A` were huge, you would start to see crazy results: when you were merging small sub-arrays with only a few elements, but very close to the top of `A`, you would see huge values for `q`, which have nothing to do with the size of `L`.

When you've made sure your code is working, you should head over to codereview.stackexchange.com. They only help with working code, but they will give you lots of pointers about how to write things in a cleaner and more readable way. Your code is full of small errors like unnecessary namespaces, unused initializations and so on (but I think it is the correct approach to get it working right before worrying about these).

Comment: Thank you so much! :) It finally works! You saved me. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

For array {3, 6, 8, 1} the correct answer is 3:

{3, 6, 8, 1} -> {3, 6, 1, 8} -> {3, 1, 6, 8}  -> {1, 3, 6, 8}